# Erro em subprocess.run( ) in Python 3.7.2

Tags: python, windows, opencv

Estou utilizando:

- `Windows 10`
- `Python 3.7.2 Shell (default IDLE) x64`

Estou tentando seguir o tutorial [LearnOpenCV tutorial](https://www.learnopencv.com/training-yolov3-deep-learning-based-custom-object-detector/), já baixei o arquivo `class-descriptions-boxable.csv` e `train-annotations-bbox.csv` através do `Git`

Fiz download dos arquivos e coloquei na mesma pasta que o arquivo `getDataFromOpenImages_snowman.py` (mostrado abaixo), mas quando eu rodo, apresenta um erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\path\getDataFromOpenImages_snowman.py", line 12, in <module>
    subprocess.run(['rm', '-rf', 'JPEGImages'])

  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py",
     line 472, in run with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:

  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py",
    line 775, in __init__ restore_signals, start_new_session)

  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py",
    line 1178, in _execute_child startupinfo)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system can not find the file specified
```

Não tenho experiência em Python, procurei por [`subprocess documentation`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html), no entanto, não consigo entender o problema. Alguém tem uma sugestão?

```
import csv
import subprocess
import os

runMode = "train"
classes = ["Snowman"]

with open('class-descriptions-boxable.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    dict_list = {rows[1]:rows[0] for rows in reader}

subprocess.run(['rm', '-rf', 'JPEGImages'])
subprocess.run([ 'mkdir', 'JPEGImages'])

subprocess.run(['rm', '-rf', 'labels'])
subprocess.run([ 'mkdir', 'labels'])

for ind in range(0, len(classes)):

    className = classes[ind]
    print("Class " + str(ind) + " : " + className)

    commandStr = "grep " + dict_list[className] + " " + runMode + "-annotations-bbox.csv"
    print(commandStr)
    class_annotations = subprocess.run(commandStr.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')
    class_annotations = class_annotations.splitlines()

    totalNumOfAnnotations = len(class_annotations)
    print("Total number of annotations : "+str(totalNumOfAnnotations))

    cnt = 0
    for line in class_annotations[0:totalNumOfAnnotations]:
        cnt = cnt + 1
        print("annotation count : " + str(cnt))
        lineParts = line.split(',')
        subprocess.run([ 'aws', 's3', '--no-sign-request', '--only-show-errors', 'cp', 's3://open-images-dataset/'+runMode+'/'+lineParts[0]+".jpg", 'JPEGImages/'+lineParts[0]+".jpg"])
        with open('labels/%s.txt'%(lineParts[0]),'a') as f:
            f.write(' '.join([str(ind),str((float(lineParts[5]) + float(lineParts[4]))/2), str((float(lineParts[7]) + float(lineParts[6]))/2), str(float(lineParts[5])-float(lineParts[4])),str(float(lineParts[7])-float(lineParts[6]))])+'\n')
```

Comment: Traduza a pergunta, você está no SOpt.

Comment: Sim. Já foi traduzida. Obrigado!

Comment: Não seria porque você está tentando fazer uma chamada ao `rm -rf` no Windows? No tutorial que tá seguindo é usado Linux...

Comment: Bom, pode ser que sim. Vou pesquisar sobre e tentar implementar. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

O `subprocess.run()` serve para executar subprocessos. Isso significa que ele deve ser usado quando você quer que o seu script rode um outro programa executável disponível em seu computador.

No caso você está executando o programa `rm` porém, de acordo com a mensagem de erro, esse comando não existe em sua máquina.

O programa `rm` é muito usado no linux para remover arquivos e diretórios, porém, ele não vem instalado no windows. Para instalá-lo no windows você pode acessar este [link do GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) e baixar.

Uma outra alternativa seria reescrever essa parte do programa para não usar subprocessos, assim, ela funcionaria em qualquer sistema operacional, independente dos programas instalados. Ficaria assim:

```
import os, shutil

# subprocess.run(['rm', '-rf', 'JPEGImages'])
shutil.rmtree('JPEGImages', ignore_errors=True)

# subprocess.run([ 'mkdir', 'JPEGImages'])
os.mkdir('JPEGImages')
```

Comment: De fato, isto pode fazer com que as linhas 12, 13, 15, 16 funcionassem. Contudo, o código utiliza-se do `subprocess` abaixo e novamente há um erro em `class_annotations = subprocess.run(commandStr.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')`. Mas obrigado!

Comment: O problema é o mesmo. A minha resposta explica o que está acontecendo. Faça o download do `grep.exe` para windows aqui http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm e use, ou então você vai precisar reescrever o que o grep faz.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado! Funcionou! Infelizmente não consigo uppar sua resposa